# Split a list on a key word which may appear multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ciscoconfparse

I've read the examples which seem similar but I am not at that level to understand the answers. I want to take the list output and write each interface as a separate line `(aka list I write to a csv)`.  I need to split the initial return list on the keyword 'interface Vlan*'

I want to  split returned list vlanlist on keyword interface `vlan*` into separate lists

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
import os

for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith(".cfg"):
        p = CiscoConfParse(filename)
        vlanlist=(p.find_all_children('^interface Vlan'))
        vlanlist.insert(0,filename)

        print(vlanlist)
```

This is one line of output. I need to split the list on keyword `"interface vlanxxx"` into separate lines

```
[ 'interface Vlan1', ' no ip address', ' shutdown', 'interface Vlan2003', ' description XXXXXX', ' ip address 10.224.6.130 255.255.255.224', ' no ip redirects', ' no ip unreachables', ' no ip proxy-arp', ' load-interval 60', ' arp timeout 420']
```

Desired OUTPUT (this may have 2-20 diferent interfaces I want to split on depending on config file)

```
['interface Vlan1' ' no ip address', ' shutdown']
['interface Vlan2003', ' description XXXXXX', ' ip address 10.224.6.130 255.255.255.224', ' no ip redirects', ' no ip unreachables', ' no ip proxy-arp', ' load-interval 60', ' arp timeout 420']
```

Comment: Could you simplify your question by separating the problematic part from all of this file stuff? Is it really relevant? When I read the question title I thought: oh, that's easy! ... and then I got distracted.

Comment: Can u give example of what desired output looks like?

Comment: Yes I will simplify

Comment: It seems you want to split on `sw01.cfg`?

Comment: simplified.  on interface vlan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further separate your returned `vlanlist` before you append the file names:

```
# First, find the index in the list where "interface Vlan" exists:
# Also, append None at the end to signify index for end of list
indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v.startswith('interface Vlan')] + [None]

# [0, 3, None]

# Then, create the list of lists based on the extracted indices and prepend with filename
newlist = [[filename] + vlanlist[indices[i]:indices[i+1]] for i in range(len(indices)-1)]

for l in newlist: print(l)

# ['test.cfg', 'interface Vlan1', ' no ip address', ' shutdown']
# ['test.cfg', 'interface Vlan2003', ' description XXXXXX', ' ip address 10.224.6.130 255.255.255.224', ' no ip redirects', ' no ip unreachables', ' no ip proxy-arp', ' load-interval 60', ' arp timeout 420']
```

Explanation for the second list comprehension:

```
newlist = [
    [filename] +                   # prepend single-item list of filename
    vlanlist[                      # slice vlanlist
        indices[i]:                # starting at the current index
        indices[i+1]               # up to the next index
    ] 
    for i in range(len(indices)-1) # iterate up to the second last index so i+1 doesn't become IndexError
]
```

If you don't like the index approach, you can try `zip` instead:

```
lists = [[filename] + vlanlist[start:end] for start, end in zip(indices[:-1], indices[1:])]
```

Comment: Your did it!  And you showed me my path.  I just didn't know what I didn't know.  You threw me with the l for my vlanlist but I finally grasped the logic and it's so elegant.  I'll try the zip as well just for skill building.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, if you're still learning make sure you check out the other answers as well as each of them show you a different approach that might be helpful in other use cases.  For `zip` it's basically creating `tuple`s of the `list`s provided, i.e. `zip(x, y)` will return a zip object of `(x[0], y[0]), (x[1], y[1])...`.  But in this case it just serves to make the code a bit more readable IMO.

Comment: Yep!  trying them all.  I am a beginner.  I've come pretty far but it's just not intuitive to me.  I do Cisco mostly but just have no end of uses for Python to help me solve problems with large networks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's highly coupled to your single test case.  You'll have to evolve it with more tests if the full dataset isn't representative of your single test case.

```
def extract(items):
  result, filename, idx = [], items[0], -1

  for x in items[1:]:
    if x.startswith('interface Vlan'):
      idx += 1
      result.append([filename])
    result[idx].append(x)

  return result

# given & expected are your example and output 
assert expected == extract(given)
```

EDIT:
... and you've already changed the inputs and outputs.

```
def extract(items):
  result, idx = [], -1

  for x in items:
    if x.startswith('interface Vlan'):
      idx += 1
      result.append([])

    if not result: continue  # assuming possible unwanted items before 'interface Vlan'
    result[idx].append(x)

  return result

assert expected == extract(given)
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and straightforward solution. Check the list for `interface Vlan` items, if it is, it creates a new list, else appends on the old list and some `.strip()` for good measure.

```
output = ['interface Vlan1', ' no ip address', ' shutdown', 'interface Vlan2003', ' description XXXXXX', ' ip address 10.224.6.130 255.255.255.224', ' no ip redirects', ' no ip unreachables', ' no ip proxy-arp', ' load-interval 60', ' arp timeout 420']

results = []

for i in output:
    if 'interface Vlan' in i:
        results.append([i.strip()])
    else:
        results[-1].append(i.strip())

>> results
 [['interface Vlan1', 'no ip address', 'shutdown'],
 ['interface Vlan2003',
  'description XXXXXX',
  'ip address 10.224.6.130 255.255.255.224',
  'no ip redirects',
  'no ip unreachables',
  'no ip proxy-arp',
  'load-interval 60',
  'arp timeout 420']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This identifies a single split point, and divides your list into two lists as specified.  The split_pos list will find all split positions; you could iterate through this if there are multiple split points.  The split condition looks for a string starting with the given text and at least three more characters, the "xxx" in your posting.

```
vlanlist = ['sw01.cfg', 'interface Vlan1', ' no ip address', ' shutdown', 'interface Vlan2003', ' description XXXXXX', ' ip address 10.224.6.130 255.255.255.224', ' no ip redirects', ' no ip unreachables', ' no ip proxy-arp', ' load-interval 60', ' arp timeout 420']
target = "interface Vlan"

split_pos = [idx for idx, str in enumerate(vlanlist) if str.startswith(target) and \
                                                        len(str) >= len(target)+3][0]

out1 = [vlanlist[0]] + vlanlist[1:split_pos]
out2 = [vlanlist[0]] + vlanlist[split_pos:]

print(out1)
print(out2)
```

Output:

```
['sw01.cfg', 'interface Vlan1', ' no ip address', ' shutdown']
['sw01.cfg', 'interface Vlan2003', ' description XXXXXX', 
 ' ip address 10.224.6.130 255.255.255.224', ' no ip redirects',
 ' no ip unreachables', ' no ip proxy-arp', ' load-interval 60', ' arp timeout 420']
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have more than 2 `interface Vlan` in the list though?

Comment: Yes; in that case, do *not* simply grab the first (only) element of `split_pos`.  Iterate through the list of split positions, grabbing the slices you need.

Comment: Right, hence my solution which is very similar to yours in nature, just that it can handle *n* of splitpos.  I note that your starting point is *after* the filename has already been prepended.  In the end I think we're both going about it pretty much the same :)